# Pore/Grain Filler Over Danish Oil

Tags: polyurethane, oiling, filler

I have two slabs:

1. redwood
2. some kind of hard wood that I think resembles a red gum wood

I have coated them in `Danish Oil` and this coating has been allowed to dry for over 10 days.

My long term goal is a smooth texture with high gloss.  So my plan is to apply `wipe on poly - clear gloss by minwax`.

To this end, I've been using the underside of each slab as a test bed for the topside of each slab.  Currently, I'm practicing the technique of applying wipe on poly and building up a film.  I've applied 8 coats to the underside of each slab and am noticing that the pores/grain in both are still evident and tactile.

Below are two images of the underside of each slab respectively (after 8 coats of wipe on poly).

With an eye to the road ahead, specifically the topside processing of each slab I have the following questions:

1. Do I need to just keep applying poly until the pores/grain fill?
2. If "no" to (1) above, is it possible to apply a pore/grain filler over Danish Oil?
3. If "yes" to (2), what are recommendations for manufacturer/product/color to use on each of the slabs?
4. If "no" to (2), will buffing and then polishing using a [paste wax by minwax](https://www.walmart.com/ip/Finishing-Paste-Wax/21469752?wmlspartner=wlpa&selectedSellerId=1194&adid=22222222227016797360&wl0=&wl1=g&wl2=c&wl3=52574386751&wl4=pla-81182831124&wl5=9031968&wl6=&wl7=&wl8=&wl9=pla&wl10=112550058&wl11=online&wl12=21469752&wl13=&veh=sem) post-applying 7 or so wipe-on-poly layers fill the pores/grain?
5. If "no" to (4), any alternatives not mentioned?

Thanks!

Redwood:
[image: redwood slab]

Red gum:
[image: red gum slab]

Comment: FYI redwood doesn't have any pores, it's a softwood. The texture you've gotten in that case at least is from the application method, not from the wood. If you apply wipe-on finishes as they're often applied these days (where you wipe off all/nearly all of the excess) you can achieve a pretty great surface with no additional sanding. With care and a bare minimum of further sanding/abrading you can achieve a look quite similar to French polishing.